# Is complement of diagonal language countable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

I tried to find out how to arrange the complement of diagonal language, but I failed. So I'm about to believe that it's not a countable language. Could you, please, help me?

Answer (score 9):

A language is a set of finite strings over some finite alphabet $\Sigma$. Therefore, *every* language is countable. You can see this by considering $\Sigma = \{0, \dots, d\}$ for some $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and now you can associate any string with a natural number written in base $d$.  To avoid the problem that, e.g., $0$ and $000$ denote the same number (and I guess $\epsilon$ counts as zero, too), we actually associate the string $x_1\dots x_n$ with the number $1x_1\dots x_n$. Thus, we have an injection from $\Sigma^*$ to $\mathbb{N}$, so $\Sigma^*$ is countable and so are all its subsets.

Comment: Strictly speaking, not all languages are defined over finite alphabets.  (But still a nice answer to the question that was clearly intended, if not actually asked.)

Comment: @AndrásSalamon And people also consider languages of infinite strings over finite (or, I guess, infinite) alphabets.

Comment: If your alphabet starts with 1, not 0, your leading-zero special cases simply go away (the empty word will be the only one to map to 0).

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That's a fair point. I guess I chose the encoding I did because $\{0,1\}$ is a very commonly used alphabet and it seems a little weird to associate strings in $\{0,1\}$ with _ternary_ numbers treating $0$ as $1$ and $1$ as $2$. But you could perfectly well argue that it's weird to associate the string $000$ with the binary number $1000\,$! :-)